# supporting separate CSS for tables & phones on NativeScript

Tags: css, nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin

How can I get support for multiple screens such as tablets and phones to work in NativeScript with Angular (I am on NS 5.1 now)? I am currently trying to use the `nativescript-platform-css` plugin, which creates classes `phone` and `tablet` classes on the `Page` element and then supply different CSS along the lines of:

```
.phone :host .photo {
  width:300;
}

.tablet :host .photo {
  height:600;
}
```

The trouble is that it works fine in some cases but in other cases don’t (at least not in angular). For example, in modals it doesn’t work really and also I found other cases that are problematic.

I could of course apply the CSS programatically going by the `nsPlatform.deviceType` global variable that the plugin creates, but that seems not so 'clean' and will require quite some code on every component that I would prefer to avoid.

The multiple screen section in the [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/supporting-multiple-screens) mention that it doesn't work for Angular and Webpack builds (although AFAIK the project is moving to webpack by default now).

Thanks for any contributing thought!

Comment: Beware you may be getting flags and votes for "_Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise._"

Comment: @csmckelvey I'll be happy to get a solution that simply works :) I'll slightly rephrase the question to reflect that.

Comment: Your modal root is page-router-outlet? If not, there won't be a page and the phone / tablet classes may not be applicable. The solution for multiple screen size in Angular  is to build seperate components and include them in your main component with a ngIf that checks for device type.

Comment: @manoj yeah in modals I need to explicitly declare <Page></Page>, but even then still it works only if I declare the classes with "/deep/" instead of ":host" (and also there is a small delay before the styles are applied). The problem is that the Angular docs say that using /deep/ has been depreciated, I would prefer to avoid that use. Also, the ":host notation is not working properly in regular (non-modal) navigation. I opened an issue here (https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-platform-css/issues/23) about that. The question is if there are better ways to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Angular doesn't work like that, Page should automatically be injected by router. So you must setup a page router outlet and a specific route for your component inside modal.

Comment: @manoj thanks but that has the same result. Plus when I add the <Page> tags the suddenly I see that the shownModallyFirst event from the nativescript-globalsevents plugin does start to fire. Anyway I can live without the modals, I am just wondering how other people are handling this.

Comment: @Joni: Did you find a good solution for different devices in Angular? I need to distinguish between tablets and desktops.

Comment: @markelc well I ended up using the platform-css with /deep/, but it is not ideal (I am hoping that :host will be supported by NS anytime soon). Then there is this also this blog by Eddy: https://www.nativescript.org/blog/tablet-support-for-nativescript-with-angular

Comment: @Joni. I saw Eddy's post. The problem for me is that when I tested: "device.deviceType === DeviceType.Tablet" the only two option are Phone and Tablet and my needs are more extensive.

I'm testing saving screen.mainScreen.heightDIPs and screen.mainScreen.widthDIPs to state (I use ngrx, but appsettings works), creating a device string based on those values, and then using the device string to deterimine css styles. It's not ideal but in my first test it worked. The question is how complicated will it be to implement throughout the app. Not sure yet. ;)